# python: Create a detached process and communicate with it via command line

Tags: python, asynchronous

I want to create a command-line tool which is a countdown timer with some custom features I need.

My idea is to use a python script to fire up a process which does the work in the background (e.g. play sound when close to the end). Once the timer process is running I would like to communicate with it via the command line (send inquiries like 'remaining' or commands like 'start XXmin' and 'stop'). There should be only a single instance of the timer process, of course.

Usage might look like

```
>>> timer start 25min

>>> timer remaining
17:34 min remaining

>>> timer stop
timer stopped.

>>> timer start 90sec
```

What would the timer process need to look like to do its work while waiting for messages to arrive? What, in turn, would the interface script need to do to fire up the process and to communicate with it later? Is using a separate process the best idea to achieve my goal?

I have no clue how to go about it. My idea sounds very simple yet almost all of what I found is concerned with the concurrency of child processes of a parent script, which is not what I want.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for here is a basic client-server architecture. You'll need two programs - one which runs in the background and listens for messages (the server), and a second that sends messages to the server, and does something with the responses (the client).

There are a *lot* of ways to do this, and the area is legitimately complex, so don't expect it to be super easy. For just starting out, I'd recommend you just try to use a simple `http.server` server using the standard library ([http server module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/http.server.html#module-http.server)). For the client side, I'd recommend the `requests` [library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). HTTP is definitely not the best possible choice for a local client-server setup, but with the existing libraries it's going to be by far the easiest to get up and running, and once you're comfortable with that, you can look into other approaches if you want to.

Comment: This looks promising, thank you. What would be the most natural approach to this task assuming free choice of programming language or framework?

Comment: Probably some sort of RPC library would be the most natural fit for this sort of task. Language really isn't very important, though Python is a great choice for projects with only one or a couple developers.

Python has a number of RPC libraries - After a little looking around I might actually recommend checking out gRPC: https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html. It looks as if getting a basic setup running will be pretty easy!

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be to use `&` in the shell to execute your script in the background. And then communicate with the process with just USR1 and USR2 signals.

In Python, I guess easiest way would be to use daemon module.

```
import daemon

def do_something():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with daemon.DaemonContext():
       do_something()
```

Or you could `fork()` your own daemon process.

```
import os

def doSomething():
    pass

def createDaemon():
    try:
        # Store the Fork PID
        pid = os.fork()

        if pid > 0:
            print 'PID: %d' % pid
            os._exit(0)

        os.chdir("/") 
        os.setsid() 
        os.umask(0) 
    except OSError, error:
        print 'Unable to fork. Error: %d (%s)' % (error.errno, error.strerror)
        os._exit(1)

    doSomething()
```

Then, for example, you could use `os.pipe` to communicate with that daemon process. On in this simple case, on a *nix system, even just signals.

Another option is to use [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.daemon) module to create the daemon process and also to communicate with it.

Comment: Thank you, this is very simple indeed. Does this approach work independent of the platform (assuming windows, linux or mac)? I'm unaware what python's `os` library is or is not doing for me.

Comment: Forking processes with os library is platform independent.